# Router config for wildcard subdomains on internal network

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, wildcard, subdomain

I'm trying to setup internal wildcard subdomains to point at my Apache vhost config (which works well).  The issue is that Windows hosts files can't support wildcard subdomain, so I'm hoping that my router and/or other solution can assist.

I have a Billion 7404VGOX router but can't see any options in the admin to configure this.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks,
JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a DNS server running on your internal network.

If you don't have an Active Directory (I'm guessing you don't), [Wikipedia has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software) of software that will do this job for you. If you were running *nix or were willing to set up a *nix virtual machine for being your DNS, then `bind` is the way to go.

The reason your router doesn't have this is because it's not really a DNS server, it's just a DNS forwarder that forwards the DNS requests it receives to the ISP's DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry for taking so long.  I've been trying to work out what the best option is.  I have multiple VMs running (for browser testing mostly) and one is Ubuntu so I could use that.  My concern is that means I need to have the Ubuntu VM running continuously and that sucks RAM already in demand from Netbeans and Photoshop - and unfortunately I have a problem with my motherboard that means I can't add more RAM!  Grr..

Answer (score 0):

Cheap alternative is to setup a [domain suffix search list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275553) on the clients.